# Change a date format in .csv file in each row

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a csv file like this:

```
text;text;text;Date    
text;text;text;Date     
text;text;text;Date
```

the date format is like this:

```
Mon 14 Nov 2016 13:07:30
```

And I want change to this format (timestamp) in each row 
`14-11-2016 23:36:33`

Comment: What's the correlation between `13:07:30` and `23:36:33`? Consider specifying the format more explicitly, by indicating something like `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 2):

Using awk and `date`:

```
$ awk -v OFS=\; -F\; -v qt="'" ' {
    str="date -d" qt $4 qt " " qt "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" qt; 
    str | getline d; 
    print $1,$2,$3,d
}' file
text;text;text;2016-11-14 13:07:30
```

It takes the 4th field (`$4`) delimited by `;` (`-F\;`), uses is as a parameter to system `date` command, reads its output to variable `d` and prints out three first fields and `d`.

Answer (score 1):

If your system supports process substitution, you can do something like this:

```
paste -d\; <(cut -d\; -f1-3 date.csv )  <(cut -d\; -f4 date.csv | date -f - '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick little write-up for you on [how to scrub CSV data in ruby](https://ruby.unicorn.tv/articles/read-and-replace-content-in-a-csv)

In short, given your input, you can scrub and convert the data with ruby like so:

```
require 'date'                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

newFile = File.new("new.csv", "w+")                                                                                                                                                                                                        
oldFile = File.read("original.csv")                                                                                                                                                                                                        

oldFile.lines.each do |line|                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  lineArray = line.split(';')                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  formattedDate = DateTime.parse(lineArray[3]).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')                                                                                                                                                 
  lineArray[3] = formattedDate                                                                                                                                                                                                             

  newFile.puts "#{lineArray.join(';')}\n"                                                                                                                                                                                                  
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

newFile.close
```

All you need to do is save this script in your directory as `parser.rb`, make sure your original csv is saved as `original.csv` (or update the script accordingly) and then run `ruby parser.rb` in terminal.

Comment: Why did you post a ruby answer when OP tagged his question with `bash` and `awk` ? I'm pretty sure I could think of a `c#` or `scheme` solution to address the OP's problem, but that'd be way out of scope...

Comment: I didn't look at the tags, just saw it come in my inbox and as I only follow ruby threads I made some assumptions. Don't hate on me because SO decided to magically subscribe me to a new topic for whatever reason.